# Computer Vision - Human Detection in Video

Tags: computer-vision

I need to detect a human in a video in realtime. I guess its not much different from detecting a human in a static image (except that the video image is usually much lower resolution). Can you guys point me in some direction?
I don't have no experience in the computer vision field, so I any link, article, video that could give me a introduction would be useful.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Lots of links to available implementations of papers via http://www.csee.wvu.edu/~xinl/source.html. For action *detection* - http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zliu/papers/SPM2010.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the most famous methods for human detection is the [Histogram of Oriented Gradients (HoG)](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf) detector. This has been implemented in the [OpenCV library](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=hog) and should be a good starting point.

Comment: The camera will be positioned in the ceilling (I forgot to mention...). Will this method still work?

Comment: Hmm, I guess if they get right underneath the camera the method will not work so well. However, you could run some tests on the detection rate for different positions around the camera and define a cone where the accuracy is unacceptably low. As you are working with video you could detect targets that are outside this region using a human detection algorithm and then use a [Kalman Filter](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=kalman#KalmanFilter) to track them as a simple blob shape if they enter the region.

Comment: Hi @Max. I want to know more about people tracking. Let's say I have a realtime reliable way to detect humans. Let's say I detect humans at a very low rate in my video stream. So, I cannot say that the rectangle in frame A points to the same person the rectangle in frame B points to just because the two rectangles are close together. Is there something I can use to tell if two persons are the same on distinct frames even if the person moves a lot from one frame to another?

Comment: @DaniloCarvalho This sounds pretty tough. Trajectory/motion modelling might give you a rough guess as to where they will be in the next frame but initializing this will be tough (perhaps you could try to figure out the direction they are moving from the direction they are facing in the first frame and refine from there). Also tracking based on the colors of clothes/skin/hair might be an option if the video feed is in color. The [condensation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation_algorithm) might be a good place to start for this type of tracking.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use HOG features.
This first method seems to be time-consuming
nevertheless it is a very successful human detection
algorithm. The second way is to optimize the HOG
algorithm by resizing the image this method results
in more than two times increase in detecting humans
in a 
 image while scarifying in the detection
accuracy mainly when persons are on the edges. The
third way consists in adapting Haar feature for
human detection this solution significantly reduces
computational cost in spite of the precision.
To evaluate the proposed method, we have
established a top-view human database.
Experimental results have demonstrated the
effectiveness and efficiency of the proposed
algorithm which gives a good ratio accuracy/time
execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for this in 2024, an effective approach would be using YOLO based detector over [Multi Object Trackers](https://paperswithcode.com/task/multi-object-tracking)(MOT) likes Deep-SORT.

Association and Re-ID modules in MOT algorithms help track consistently throughout even with cases missing and unreliable detections in between frames.

[This](https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/yolo_tracking) is a helpful github repo to start with.